# System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported

Tags: json, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am trying to store a shopping cart containing a List of CartLine (and each CartLine contains another List), to a ProtectedSessionStorage or LocalStorage in Blazor serverside:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ProtectedBrowserStorage;
using Cloudcrate.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser.Storage;

...
session.SetAsync("Cart", cart);
storage.SetItemAsync("Cart", cart);
```

But I get the error:

**System.Text.Json.JsonException**: 'A possible object cycle was detected which is not supported. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 0.'

When I configure depth:

```
services.AddRazorPages();
            .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.MaxDepth = 3);
```

it has no effect and when I use [JsonIgnore] so that I can manually cycle the lists to store and retrieve, JsonIgnore does not work and I get the same error.
There is an alpha version of this json library but when I search I find nothing. What do I do?

**EDIT**: 
I have three classes to store, But the simplest one is:

```
 public class CultureChanger
{
    public CultureInfo Current { get; private set; } = new CultureInfo("en");

    public Action OnCultureChange;

    public void ChangeCulture(string cultureName)
    {
        Current = new CultureInfo(cultureName);
        OnCultureChange?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

I manually and laboriously, iterate and store the nested classes and Enumerables and tuples inside these classes, first by using JsonIgnore and then manually store the class, But it should be automatic, since it can be configured using MaxDepth.

Comment: Post the code of classes you try to serialize. it'll help

Comment: (I'm just guessing since there is no code shared.) Business models can have navigation properties that cause cycles when trying to serialize an instance. Usually (flat) Dto version of the model is used for serializations. Map the models to Dtos that does not have back and forth references.